# How to change background of date in calendarview

Tags: android, calendar, android-drawable, android-calendar

I am using `calendarview`and what I want to change is the `background view of date`,now  suppose if user has clicked on 15th December so after clicking on it a image which is stored in drawable folder should appear instead of 15th. Is there any method so that I can get all the date as a separate view or any other idea ?

Answer (score -1):

You could extend the native CalenderView to create your own CustomCalendarView and make any desired changes in appearance.

You can find the code for the native CalendarView from here http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/2.1_r2/com/android/calendar/CalendarView.java

Comment: i havent worked on it also when i am downloading it, It is giving me only Calendarview. java, Can you please tell me how to download whole calendar package ?

Comment: you have the code for calender view. extend you calender view class to CalenderView and override the functions

Comment: sir i want to download whole calendar package from above link. How can i download it ?